2022 Moderator Election Q&A – Question Collection

The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it here.


Cryptography Stack Exchange is scheduled for an election next week, 2022-03-21. In connection with that, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates. This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.
Here’s how it’ll work:

Until the nomination phase, (so, until 2022-03-21 at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post one question per answer.

If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of [text](link), as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.

This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into currently.

We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The following two questions are guaranteed to be included:

How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc. a question that you feel shouldn’t have been?


The community team may also include the following three questions if the community doesn’t supply enough questions.

In your opinion, what do moderators do?
A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?


At the start of the nomination phase, the Community Team will select up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. We exclude any suggested questions that are negatively scored.

We will post the final questionnaire on the Election page. Candidates will have the option to fill out the questionnaire, and their answers will appear beneath their intro statements.
This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.



If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

What has your involvement in moderation in the past? For example, have you helped maintain particular tags, been active in review queues, or provided help on meta? How do you see this changing as you step into a more official role?


What will be your action when a question includes multiple questions that have dupes of almost all of them? Consider it has 5 questions and 4 has duplicates.


How would the fact that a question is about cryptocurrency influence you in possibly the most common hard decision a moderator has to make: deciding about closing a question as off-topic?

It is usually left up to the user base to decide if a question is on topic or not. In which cases do you think it is prudent to close the question yourself? In which cases would you try and salvage the question?

This is just a generic question for getting to know the moderator. The answers may not reflect the actual actions taken by the prospective mod when installed. Guidance will be given to the new mod once the election has concluded.

We haven't got 3 votes to close a question on the main site, while 5 votes are required. Would you close the questions when the votes reach 3?

@PaulUszak did you see this? Testing three-vote close and reopen on 13 network sites. It turns out 5 is too high even for [so],

Why did you use the word "even"?

@PaulUszak there are lots of people there to vote than cryptography.se. Isn't this clear?

Do you see any conflict of interest with moderators answering questions?

What timezone are you in? More generally, at what hours of the day do you expect to be online for taking care of our moderation duties?

It will  be good if the current moderators also indicate their status.

We are all three in CET. However - up till now - that hasn't had too much of an impact. I don't think it should be a main deciding factor for choosing mods as it isn't a personal trait, but it is of course up to you all to call that :)

@MaartenBodewes To be honest, I carried the last two questions from other sites that suit us so that we can have various questions. And having different time zones will obviously relax your burden. Thanks again for your services.

Yes, it would certainly be a boon if we are a bit more spread out, but I think quality should prevail over availability - at least when it comes to timezones, not general availability. And in that case we get what we get.

And, well, at least if Brian is going to be a candidate we will have a different one :)

What difference do you see between this forum  and other social media?

Just a nitpick, but SE isn't a forum. People on MSE don't like when people call it that.

How will you try to attract more women to this forum?

Would anyone dare to explain the downvote?
